# Delay Laravel Notification By Certain Time using Notifcation::send() facade

Tags: laravel

How do I delay notifications using the notification Facade in Laravel

```
Notification::send($users,new AccountRegistered($user))->delay();
```

the above doesn't seem to exist

Comment: The delay method requires a timeframe for how long it should be delayed

Comment: i know but how do i use the Notification Facade to apply delay, the delay method is unavailable for the facade

Comment: You need to queue the notification in order to delay it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `AccountRegistered` notification class, you can update the `$delay` property and set it's value in seconds;

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->delay(15);
}
```

Or call it after initializing the object:

```
Notification::send($users, (new AccountRegistered($user))->delay(15));
```